# How do I keep a CALayer, sublayer of a CATiledLayer, from changing it's scale after a zoom?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming, catiledlayer

I have a CATiledLayer that is used to display a PDF page (this CATiledLayer is the layer type of my UIView which is a subview of a UIScrollView). I want to add overlay markers on this page. So I add a sublayer to my CATiledLayer. This sublayer again hosts the different marker's layers and acts as a grouping layer.

So graphically, I have: (keep in mind that I have multiple markers which are CALayers also, this is ascii art after all)

```
pdf page (CATiledLayer)
----------------------
|  CALayer           |
|  +---------+       |
|  |  +----+ |       |
|  |  |mker| |       |
|  |  +----+ |       |
|  +---------+       |
|                    |
----------------------
```

I have set up the canonical drawLayer:inContext: in my view for drawing the pdf.

When I zoom to have more detail, the pdf gets rendered correctly, but the markers get scaled. No matter what I do to the bounds of the CALayer, my markers always become bigger and appear jagged.

I would like to have the markers always the same size, as when they were initialized and first shown when the view was drawn. Is this possible ? or am I using a wrong approach ? Should I do special drawing for my contained CALayer in the drawLAyer:inContext: message ?

As you see, there are things that I am missing to resolve my problem. Thank you for any help you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker is scaling because it inherits the transforms of the superlayer. Create another top level `CALayer` that contains the markers and other objects you don't want scaled and overlay it on top of `CATiledLayer`.

Comment: I finally ended up using another uiview that contain the markers. I beleive it has the same effect. I gather that it is not possible to override the transform inheritance. Thanks for the response.