# Preventing CALayer Sublayers From Getting Scaled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, zooming, calayer, scale

I have some CALayers in a layer hosted view. Each of these layers has additional layers to hold (1) a close button, and (2) a resize handle. These additional 'control' layers are added as sublayers to the parent layer.

Currently, when I zoom the workspace in which these layers reside, everything scales -- including these control layers. However, I would like to prevent these control layers from scaling.

Is there a way to override the behaviour of having scale transforms being applied to all sublayers, without having to override the drawInContext: method for each control layer (presumably to invert any existing scale transform -- assuming this is possible) and without having to manually send each of these control layers a setNeedsDisplay: with every zoom?

I found this thread which discusses doing something similar but the discussion goes in the direction of CATiledLayers which is not what I'm looking for here.

[Redrawing CALayer subclass when super layer is scaled](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/Jul/msg00633.html)

Also, this post asks a somewhat related question but the responses do not apply to my situation, since I cannot overlay the controls -- they must be part of the layer hierarchy.

[How do I keep a `CALayer`, sublayer of a `CATiledLayer`, from changing it's scale after a zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2985763/2547229)

Comment: I ended up solving this problem by overriding the layoutSublayers method of my custom CALayers, obtaining the accumulated scale transform of the layer hierarchy, and applying the inverse transform to the control sublayers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by overriding the layoutSublayers method of my custom CALayers, obtaining the accumulated scale transform of the layer hierarchy, and applying the inverse transform to the control sublayers.

Comment: Did you call `[layer setNeedsLayout]` in the `scrollViewDidZoom:` delegate method of your view controller for the effected views?

Comment: Yes, and no. The application was using AppKit not UIKit. As such UIScrollView and UIScrollViewDelegate were not available. But if you are using UIKit, the way you suggest is one way to do it. 

In this app a single layer-hosted view hosts a content layer, which in turn holds many sublayers. The zooming/scaling transform is applied to the content layer directly and then `setNeedsLayout` is sent to all item layers within the content layer so that sublayer controls can set their inverse transforms in order to appear to remain a fixed size.